# Slow down the call to a specific function

Tags: java, methods

I have a game loop here, that calls the tick method. Inside the tick method, other tick methods are called. How would I slow down the call to input.tick() without slowing down the whole program? Putting a `Thread.sleep();` anywhere in the tick methods slows down the whole program and that is not what I want.

```
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        while(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println(ticks + " tps, " + frames + " fps");
            ticks = 0;

            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

```
  public void tick(){
    input.tick(); // How do I slow down the call to this?

    if(gameState){
        player.tick();
        player.move();
        collision();
        treeline.move();
        obstacleHole.move();
        obstacleWolf.move();
        coin.move();
        coin.tick();
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried yield and join

Comment: put the call to tick in a thread and then sleep that thread.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try those suggestions.

Comment: his problem i assume is his tick calling other ticks and thus sleep will delay calling of other ticks as well and he wants a slow execution of outer tick but inner ticks should work normal.
Now from slow down their are two possibilities 1. execution after a period of time i.e. sleep or 2. low priority of execution ... waiting for OP response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are doing a GUI application and the code you are showing runs on the Event Dispatch Thread. The `sleep`s make the EDT freeze and be unable to update the GUI. What you must do instead is use the `javax.swing.Timer` class to postpone the execution of the code.

If you want to `tick` at regular intervals, then just reschedule the same task again in the handler submitted to `Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Thread to call `tick()` in a deferred way, something like this:

```
private static final Timer TIMER = new Timer();

// ...

public void tick(){

    TIMER.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        void run() {
            input.tick(); // Your tick method
        }


    }, 1000 /* delay in milliseconds */)

    // ... rest of your method

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input.tick() method collects the input of the player (e.g. key presses) it does no seem appropriate to delay it.

Perhaps you might be interested in implementing a Keyboard Input Polling mechanism. (see [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-keyboard-and-mouse-r2439) for an example).

This is a usual technique in games so you do not respond to the input of the player in the usual way you would with other GUI applications. Instead you collect all the user input e.g. in a queue and then you *poll* that queue to read input at your own speed (e.g. 30 times per second).

I hope it helps